# My Newly Bought Fifa 16 isn't working

Tags: xbox-360, fifa-16

My mom went on a business trip to the US and bought me a Fifa 16 for the Xbox 360 which is what I have. I currently live in Korea so it is nearly impossible to go back to the store that she bought it in. When I put in the CD the xbox says its an unrecognized disc. There's no scratches on the back. But there were two silver stickers on the middle of the cd were the hole is. So I took them off. Also the cd case doesn't have a cover. Is that normal? My mom says that it was like that when she bought it.

Comment: Can't say for sure but aren't there things about where the game is bought vs the region you're playing in? That you can't usually or that there are restrictions prohibiting it?

Comment: @n_palum Pretty sure that should result in a different error message.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the disk? What kind of "silver stickers"?

Comment: Could your mother bought a pirated version by mistake, and your console isn't unlocked, so it wont work?